# Rate limiting design

Tags: distributed-system, redis, rate-limiting

I am designing rate limiting in my application in which the rules can be dynamic. I have a basic design in which every request is validated against the rate limiting quota, which is stored in redis. As the system scales, redis will become the bottleneck and I want to cache the quotas in memory to speed up the response time. Now the challenge is to sync the in memory values with the ones in redis. Are there any algorithms or whitepapers which can guide in solving this?

Comment: Such in-memory stuff is probably a greater threat to scalability than Redis, because keeping state in-memory prevents horizontal scaling (unless you do sharding, but that has its own issues, and in any case you could use multiple Redis instances as well). There are some tricks though if quotas don't have to be relaxed perfectly, assuming a cached value: if a lot of quota remains, just decrement the count in the background without waiting to see if it dropped to zero. Or use probabilistic. E.g. instead of decrementing 1 quota ever request, do 5 approximately every 5 requests.

Answer (score 2):

> redis will become the bottleneck

What makes you say that?

Redis is intended to be used in a context of a scalable application, and is itself *quite* scalable. As an example of applications of scale, Twitter, GitHub, Snapchat, Craigslist, and StackOverflow [do use Redis](https://redis.io/docs/about/users/).

> Now the challenge is to sync the in memory values with the ones in redis.

No, the actual challenge is to make in-memory cache work *at all*. A basic challenge: user A has 500 requests remaining, and already performed 499 requests. The user performs an additional request that is proceeded by node 1. Now the node 1 knows that the user reached the quotas. A few milliseconds later, user A hit node 2. How does node 2 knows that the user should be rejected?...